# What is the simplest way to dynamically load routes in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I am building an angular app and what i'm trying to accomplish is have an array of objects where i would keep the basic info about each module (the url, the controller name) so i would have a single service for the initialization, and it would get called on each route with a different url to fetch the server data with ajax calls so i have the corresponding data available in each controller by the time it is loaded.

Back with a pretty error:

```
modules = [{
  name: Scan,
  url: packing/scan,
  controllerName : packer
}];

var Application = angular.module('ReporterApplication', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.select']);

/**
 * Handles the initialization by fetching server data on module run
 */

Application.service('Initialize', ['$http', function($http)
{

    this.serverData = function(route) 
    {
        return $http.get(route + '.action')
            .then(function(response)
            {                         
                return response.data;
            });

    };

}])


Application.config(['$routeProvider', '$interpolateProvider',

    function($routeProvider, $interpolateProvider) {

        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');



        for (var i=0; i < 1; i++) {
            var index = i; // for some weird reason i is 1 by the time initData is run
            $routeProvider.when('/' + modules[i].url + '.html', {
                templateUrl: modules[i].url + '.html',
                controller: modules[i].name + 'Controller' + ' as ' + modules[i].controllerName,
                resolve: {
                  initData : ['Initialize', function(Initialize) {
                    return Initialize.serverData('/' + modules[index].url)
                  }] 
                }

            })
        };   etc more code
```

scan.js

```
Application.controller('ScanController', ['$scope', '$http', 'initData', function($scope, $http, initData) {

    var packer = this;

    packer.initData = initData;
    packer.packedToday = initData.ordersPackedToday; etc more code
```

And this throws me

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: initDataProvider <- initData <- ScanController

Update: Solved that one, but now it seems that controller doesn't load data

Update: Solved that too. Everything seems to work, and im the best :D

Comment: What do you mean with `run a loop of whens`? Show what you need to execute there

Comment: Services don't return anything...why is there a return statement in there?

Comment: Well, does your theory work or not? Have you tried anything that didn't work, and if you did, can you elaborate on what the actual outcome was compared to what you expected? We can't see your screen, so you'll have to tell us the specifics

Comment: check the edit i did